# Excel rows of data suddenly disappeared after undoing deletion of unrelated rows. Version history suddenly blank. Get my data back?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-recovery, microsoft-excel-2016, sharepoint, version-control

I have been editing an Excel workbook for 6 days. The workbook is saved in sharepoint and also marked to always be kept on my laptop. I have saved this .xlsx file dozens of times in the last few days.

I was editing the spreadsheet this afternoon when I noticed that a `sumifs` value had suddenly decreased (even from just 5 minutes before). I looked around and found that a random 7 rows of data had magically disappeared (deleted).

- When I say random, I mean it: rows 65:67, 71, 75, 81:83
- I did not hide any rows/columns, nor did I delete these rows myself. (YES, I'VE CHECKED FOR HIDDEN CELLS).
- If I UNDO, I can go through a number of steps that I know I performed AFTER last seeing those rows in place but without getting those missing rows to return themselves. It's as if they never existed!

I tried using both sharepoint's and Excel's built-in version recovery tools, but in both instances it claims I have no versions except the one I'm currently working on.

**Is there any way to get my data back??**

---

Possible thoughts:

- The last two things I remember doing recently were the following:

  1. I deleted 4-5 rows (not the ones containing the data I've lost), and then I decided to restore those rows a few seconds later using ctrl+z (undo). It was shortly after this that I noticed the data was missing.
  2. About 5 minutes before I noticed the data were missing, I had had multiple gigabytes of MS PowerPoint files converted and compiled into a pdf using Adobe Acrobat. After combining these files into a new binder, it threw an error (I don't remember what -- since I just dismissed it) but opened up the combined binder anyway. Could I have overloaded my machine in some way?

**Update:**

**I saved a copy of the file, and opened up the copy to experiment. I deleted the same 4 unrelated rows I had previously and then hit ctrl+z. Lo and behold, another group of random (unrelated) rows disappeared!! And I can't get them back. They just don't exist anymore! (not hidden; gone!) whaaaat???**

- See below for videos.

---

<sup>Specs:</sup>

- <sup>Excel version: `Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13929.20222) 64-bit`</sup>
- <sup>OS: `Windows 10 enterprise version 1909 build 18363.1316`</sup>
- <sup>Processor: `Intel i7-10510U CPU @ 1.8 GHz 2.30`</sup>
- <sup>Ram: `16 GB`</sup>

---

1 isolated example:
[image]

Multiple examples:
[image]

Note: since I had to crush the quality to get these to 2Mib, I'll copy the first column's function below for reference:

```
=IF(J53="CORRECT","A", (IF(L53="CORRECT","B",IF(N53="CORRECT","C",IF(P53="CORRECT","D",IF(R53="CORRECT","E","CHECK ANSWER"))))))
```

As you can see, I also have conditional formatting in place, which applies to these rows as well.

Comment: I would try to get a video recording of this happening and then report the bug to Microsoft.

Comment: @niemiro I have taken a video. Do you know an efficient way to report this to Microsoft?

Comment: First, can you start Excel in Safe Mode by holding down the Ctrl key as you double click on the icon, then click Yes. This disables add-ons and third party code. Does the problem still occur? Also, can you go to File > Account > Update Options > Update Now, just to make very sure you're on the latest version (I'm on 20296). If it's still a problem, is it possible for you to upload a relatively minimal non-confidential workbook which exhibits this behaviour for you?  I cannot quickly replicate this using just your formula. Also, please use "Send a Frown" - very essential.

Comment: If after trying those basic steps you still have a problem I'll try my best to draw some attention to this issue. I cannot promise to get any traction but I have a few contacts and will see what I can do. Also, if you're part of an enterprise you can try reporting this through the support person assigned to your company as quite an efficient channel.

Comment: If you dont save this to sharepoint/onedrive and simply have it as a local file, do you still get this issue?